# Can I addClass directly to img tag in a container?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on an iTunes style cover flow with Jquery. I don't use the Jquery framework all that often. I don't want to use a plugin, most of them seem like overkill for what I want. http://jsfiddle.net/zorikii/cL63y/

Currently, I am just trying to remove the active tag from an img element.

```
$(".imgFrame img").removeClass(function(index, currentClass) {
    var removedClass;
    if ( currentClass === "active" ) {
        removedClass= "active";
    }
    return removedClass;
});
```

The classes are declared as follows:

```
.imgFrame
.imgFrame > img
.imgFrame.active > img
```

EDIT: HTML:

```
<div class="imgFrame active">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x75"/>
</div>
<div class="imgFrame">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x75"/>
</div>
```

I have a feeling `$(".imgFrame img")` is not what I am looking for, though I have seen Jquery objects like that before in a different context.

Comment: Don't use removeClass() nor addClass() as a customized name function!

Comment: there is also <element>.classList in modern browsers, that is a native javascript interface and does not require jquery.

Comment: The problem is ... You wish to remove class from the div and not the img ... but in code you are trying to remove class from img and not the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `$('.imgFrame').addClass('active');` and `$('.imgFrame.active').removeClass('active');` to add & remove those classes. However if you want to do something a little more indepth like check if the next() item element is available to addClass you can do something like this:

```
$('#btnNext').on('click', function() {
    var $curImg = $('.imgFrame.active'),
        $nextImg = $curImg.next();
    if ($nextImg.length) {
        $nextImg.addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.imgFrame').first().addClass('active');
    }
    $curImg.removeClass('active');
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psyon001/cL63y/4/) example with the code from your fiddle.

Comment: And thanks for the `&text= `. I didn't know placehold accepted post vars.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking to remove the class `active` from the `img` element you can simply your code to this:

```
$('.imgFrame img').removeClass('active');
```

The check in the function you pass to the method is redundant as jQuery does this internally anyway.

To help improve the selector you're using I'd need to see the HTML code you have.

Comment: I tried that too in the beginning and it didn't work. I will need to, at some point, apply the active class to the next or previous .imgFrame in a group so I switched to the more complex function. I'll add my HTML to the OP.

Comment: The current function you have has the exact same functionality as the code I posted. If you are seeing differences, could you please edit your original question to include all relevant javascript and HTML code.

Comment: No you are correct. My function and your script do have the same functionality. Sorry. I meant I will add more to it later. Right now I'm just trying to get removeClass to actually remove a class. Once I get to that point, I will add the active class to one of the other imgFrame divs.

Comment: I don't know if you saw the HTML I added to my question. Update: `$('.imgFrame').removeClass('active');` made it work. I see what I did wrong.